# Using PHP form validation on jQuery form submission

Tags: php, jquery, forms

How do I use my php form validation when submitting my form via jQuery?

Presently, I have the form validation setup in PHP however it's not being called on submit. Therefore, I can submit an empty form, which I don't want.

**How do I change this so my php form validation is being used before submitting?**

jquery

```
(function() {
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Disables default action of form submitting
    $.post('create.php', $(this).serialize(), function() { 
        console.log('Submission entered');
        window.location = 'contact_form.html'; // Redirect to contact_form.html
    });
})
})();
```

php

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
$nameError = null;
$classError = null;

$name = $_POST['name'];
$class = $_POST['class'];

$valid = true;

// if $_POST['name'] is empty then assign the $nameError with a value
if (empty($name)) {
    $nameError = 'Please enter a name';
}

if (empty($class)) {
    $classError = 'Please enter a class';
}

// If valid execute PDO INSERT
if ($valid) {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO class(name, class_id) values(?, ?)";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(
        $name,
        $class
    ));
    Database::disconnect();
```

Comment: Since php is run on the server this isn't possible (you must send the form to the server in order to process it). You can howerver make an ajax request to your php script or something like that.

Comment: Isn't valid always set to true with your code?

Comment: @Cyclone So what is the ideal way to handle this? Use client side jQuery Validation plugin or ? Or is this not even ideal to submit forms this way?

Comment: If you want any validation to happen before you submit the form, doesn't that mean you need to do it in your JavaScript and not PHP? Remember PHP only gets to know about your form and its contents(data) when it's submitted. Use something like jQuery validate And ensure that the form is valid before $.post is called.

Comment: Well you can do it in PHP if you use AJAX. Can't check for things like duplicates in pure jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this by sending an ajax request to my script like this:

```
$('#your-form').submit(function() {
  // make ajax request
  $.ajax({
    url:'validate.php',
    data:$(this).serialize(),
    success:function(response) {
      // check if validation when ok
      // your script needs to send back a response
      // that tells if the validation passed or not
      // if the form is empty for instance you could either 
      // check it before making the ajax request or
      // perhaps return something in `response` that notifies you of this
      // then you could show an alert or something like that
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Another way would be to use jquery to check so the form isn't empty before sending it to your validation script:

```
$('#your-form').submit() {
  // check so form isn't empty
  $(':input').each(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '')
      // field was empty so return false
      return false;
  });
  // send form data to server
  return true;
});
```

Comment: Which solution did you deside to use?